# Add two values in xslt that sometimes can be null

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to add to values from a xml to another one using xslt. I am using xml version 1.

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(/fields/field[@name='value1'])+number(/fields/field[@name='value2'])"/>
```

How could I do this if value1 or value2 sometimes would be empty and produce and NaN?

I know that I can use if and when to see if value1 or value2 is not empty but let's say I can't check that. How could I solve this?

What I would like to do is if "number(/fields/field[@name='value2'])" would produce a NaN it should be the number 0 then it would work.

Best regards
Joe

Comment: Why would you not be able to "check that"?

Comment: My own solution was translate(number(/fields/field[@name='value1']),'NaN','') for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if "number(/fields/field[@name='value2'])" would produce a NaN it
>   should be the number 0

You could try something like this:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="coerce" NaN="0" />
...
<xsl:variable name="a" select="format-number(/fields/field[@name='value1'], '#', 'coerce')"/>
<xsl:variable name="b" select="format-number(/fields/field[@name='value2'], '#', 'coerce')"/>
...
<xsl:value-of select="$a + $b"/>
```

Note: the formatting used in the example assumes integer input.

Answer (score 3):

@michael.hor257k has already given a correct solution - please accept *his* answer. This is just to contribute an illustration of the method.

As you can see, the use of `format-number` achieves the same effect as a common `xsl:choose` to decide whether the content of `field` is an number or not (it appears you expressly decided against using `xsl:choose`).

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fields>
   <pair>
      <field name="value1">2</field>
      <field name="value2">3</field>
   </pair>
   <pair>
      <!--number as strings-->
      <field name="value1">"2"</field>
      <field name="value2">"3"</field>
   </pair>
   <pair>
      <!--empty-->
      <field name="value1"/>
      <field name="value2"/>
   </pair>
</fields>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/fields">
      <xsl:for-each select="pair">
         <xsl:variable name="summands">
            <xsl:for-each select="field">
               <field>
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="number(.) != .">0</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                     </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
               </field>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:variable>
         <result-a>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($summands/field)"/>
         </result-a>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//pair" mode="b"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:decimal-format name="coerce" NaN="0" />

   <xsl:template match="pair" mode="b">
      <xsl:variable name="a" select="format-number(field[1], '#', 'coerce')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="b" select="format-number(field[2], '#', 'coerce')"/>
      <result-b>
         <xsl:value-of select="$a + $b"/>
      </result-b>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result-a>5</result-a>
<result-a>0</result-a>
<result-a>0</result-a>
<result-b>5</result-b>
<result-b>0</result-b>
<result-b>0</result-b>
```

Comment: Uhm, I think you will see a difference between the two methods if value1 = 5 and value2 is empty.

Comment: No difference if one of them is empty, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: result-a will be 0, result-b will be 5. Isn't this what you get?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I think I misunderstood the OP's intent. Currently, if one of the two fields is empty, the whole sum is 0 instead of just outputting the value of the other field. I'll edit my post.

Comment: It was easier just to use translate(value1,'NaN','0')

Comment: @Joe "*It was easier just to use translate(value1,'NaN','0')*" This cannot be the answer to your question, since the input value cannot be NaN.

Comment: @Joe I wrote: "@michael.hor257k has already given a correct solution - please accept his answer." and I'd appreciate if you did exactly that.

Comment: What I meant was translate(number(/fields/field[@name='value1']),'NaN','0'), and sure I can give him the correct answer if you'd like.

Comment: @Joe That actually might not be a bad approach, although the actual result will be "00". You should be using `translate(number(…), 'aN', '0')` instead. I'll have to ponder if there can be some form of input that would trip this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works for the special situation where you are certain that each node will either contain a valid number or the node will be missing.

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/fields/field[@name='value1'] | /fields/field[@name='value2'])"/>
```

This creates a node-set by unioning the two fields, and then sums the nodes in the node-set.  If a node is missing, it will be omitted from the node-set and won't cause `NaN`.  If all the nodes are missing it will return `0`.

Limitations are that present but empty nodes will cause `NaN`, as will nodes that contain text.

Answer (score -1):

You may try the xpath
    boolean(number(//number1))
that return true if the value is a number.
You may create a variable that store the value converter or 0 (if is NAN) and then make the sum (sotty for my english)